# R: return date from element in time series

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a way to get the time stamp of an arbitrary element in time series object in R? Let me give you an example of what I mean. Imagine you had a series:

```
library(foreign)
bjg <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/air2.dta")
airline.ts <- ts(bjg[, 1], start=c(1949,1), freq=12)
```

The function `time()` returns *all* time stamps for the entire series.

```
> head(time(airline.ts))
[1] 1949.000 1949.083 1949.167 1949.250 1949.333 1949.417
```

But it doesn't work if I want the time stamp of a particular element, say

```
> time(airline.ts[6])
[1] 1
attr(,"tsp")
```

Why is that? Is there a way to extract the time information of a given element?

Comment: This could be a bit off-topic, as it is not directly related to the statistics of time series. stackoverflow might be a better platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` takes "a univariate or multivariate time-series, or a vector or matrix."

How about `time(airline.ts)[6]`?

Comment: That's it. Can't believe I didn't think of that myself... But thanks.

Comment: Was going to answer this, I came here with the same question and then theanswer struck me as I read the posted question; I'm upvoting this instead :-)

Answer (score -2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675484/get-date-of-timeseries-object

says to use index

so in your example

```
index(airline.ts)
```